# Cannot display the list in PDF format

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, pdf

I have a link on my view. When user clicks on that link, my code gets a list from database using ajax call and displays it.

Now I want to add one more link so that when user clicks on it, the list will be got from database using ajax and **displayed in PDF format** so that user can easily **print it** or **save pdf file** and no other info will be shown to user (like webpage header, footer, menu, etc).

I have researched a lot and could not find any solutions for this. Could you please tell me if it is possible to do and give me some ideas to get the work done.

Comment: Do you want to create the pdf on the server and then retrieve it with an ajax request or do you want to create the pdf with js on the client?

Comment: create the pdf with js on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at LaTeX. You can simply create the latex string for the PDF and compile it. Either on client side with an js LaTeX compiler or on the server.

(See for example: https://manuels.github.io/texlive.js)